Get visitor current city via API or display the city the user searched for
I am writing a simple PHP script to display all my available stores in google map. If the user just came in, I need to set the user current city as default city using geolocation (3rd party); otherwise, if the user searches for a city in the web form, then I display all my stores in the city searched by the user.
It is my first PHP script ever, so please be kind.
<?php
if (isset($_POST['place'])) {
$city = $_POST['place'];
}else{
$city = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$city));
   
if($query && $query['status'] == 'success')
{
$display = $query['city'];
}
?> 
<div>
your city is: <?php echo "$display"?>
 or
your city is: <?php echo $display ?></div>
<?php exit(); ?>


Choose a simpler response format: JSON
I haven't used the API from ip-api.com before so I decided to take a look at the documentation. In the Geolocation API section selected the link under sub-heading Response formats : PHP. On that page I see this warning:

\$
\bbox[pink]{\large\sf Deprecated}\$
\$
\bbox[pink]{\color{#85262c}\sf{\textrm{Use JSON. Almost all PHP sites now support json_decode(), }\\\textrm{and it's faster than unserialize()}}}\$

And similarly, on the PHP documentation for the unserlialize() function is this warning:

Warning
Do not pass untrusted user input to unserialize() regardless of the options value of allowed_classes. Unserialization can result in code being loaded and executed due to object instantiation and autoloading, and a malicious user may be able to exploit this. Use a safe, standard data interchange format such as JSON (via json_decode() and json_encode()) if you need to pass serialized data to the user.
If you need to unserialize externally-stored serialized data, consider using hash_hmac() for data validation. Make sure data is not modified by anyone but you.

Thus it would be better in terms of security and performance to use the JSON response format and decode it with json_decode().
Ensure arrays contain an index before referencing it, or coalesce to null
It is good that the first condition checks to see if $_POST['place'] is set before utilizing it:

if (isset($_POST['place'])) {


However the corresponding else block references $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] which is not guaranteed to be set1:

$city = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


If that array element is not set, the code may need to display an error or obtain the IP Address with another means.
The null coalescing operator, available with PHP 7.0+2, could be used to provide a fallback value when the array element is not set - for example:
$city = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?? '104.18.43.226';

Ensure unserialized value is array with element
For these conditions:

if($query && $query['status'] == 'success')


$query could be anything truthy as unserialize() can return multiple types including array and object. $query could be an array with at least one element though that does not guarantee the key status is set, thus it would be wise to also check that $query is an array with is_array() and the key exists with array_key_exists().
